# How do I know if my index.html is being cached in my CRA app? And why is it not present in network tab?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, create-react-app, browser-cache, cache-control

I want to set `Cache-Control: no-cache` for my index.html, [as recommended in docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/).

For my js chunks, I can locate them in my dev tools' network tab and see the headers there:
[image: cache-control header visible in network tab]

But my `index.html` is not present in the network tab:
[image: no results given for "index" search in network tab]

Why is that? And how can I make sure it has the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header on it?

I can see index in sources tab
[image]

The app is served by production server (not by CRA dev server), and CRA service worker is disabled.

Comment: You're searching for resources with `index` in them in your browser tools. Are you including `index.html` in the URL that you load? Or fetching it by directory, and having that file served by default?

Comment: Its the index that loads the rest. How come do you want to see index in the network call ?

Comment: @Joe : It's CRA single-page app, so It should be included with in response to all urls.

Comment: @juxhinbleta Yes, Index loads the rest of the resources. But first, it has to be laoded itself. I don't really understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I don't see a request labeled "index" in the network tab is because I am not requesting `index.html` directly, I get it as a response when requesting a specific in-app url. I can find the respective request in devtools network tab under current URL, and it has `text/html` in the `type` column.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you want to turn off the server's caching for index.html.

There are many ways to do this.
Here are some configurations you can do on the server-side.

NGINX: (nginx.conf)

```
location / {
    gzip_static on;
    try_files $uri @index;
}

location @index {
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    expires 0;
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
```

IIS: (web.config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>    
  <location path="index.html">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>    
</configuration>
```

or you can use html [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1341133/6670104) configuration.

Comment: I know that. I already attempted to set cache-control. I now want to test if it is set correctly. That is why I want to locat index.html in my network tab

Comment: If you don't see index.html in your console, probably your domain name is your index.html. This is because index.html  configured "default page" on the server. Please check how to work URL Rewrite engine on the server.